# Log4j fails to log into file

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I googled "Spring + log4j", and here is what I get. When running Eclipse + Tomcat, I can see logs in Eclipse console, but I can't find any custom log file in Tomcat. Is there any thing misconfigured in my log4j.properties?

```
# Root Logger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, logfile  

### direct log messages to stdout ###  
log4j.logger.com.ibatis = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate = DEBUG, logfile  

log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement = DEBUG, logfile  
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet = DEBUG, logfile  

############################## Console Log Configuration ##############################  
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%5p] - %c -%F(%L) -%m%n 

############################## File Log Configuration ##############################  
log4j.appender.logfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender   
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize = 100K  
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex = 100 
log4j.appender.logfile.File = ${webApp.root}/logs/swinguserver.log  
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
# What does Append=true mean?
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
```

${webApp.root} is declared in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webApp.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I thought swinguserver.log would be created in D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\logs, but nothing is.

When I change ${webApp.root} to ${catalina.home} as @SachinSarawgi suggested, I can get swinguserver.log under Tomcat 7.0\logs. How could I configure log4j to write log under Tomcat 7.0/webapps/ROOT/logs?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In place of ${webApp.root} please try to use ${catalina.home} and check if you are getting log file.

Comment: Have you tried searching for *.log in that tree under webapps? And in config it sais "log**s**" , not "log"

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Yes, I can get swinguserver.log file in Tomcat 7.0\logs folder when using  ${catalina.home}

Comment: @Fildor I've searched, but get nothing. And when I change ${webApp.root} to ${catalina.home}, I can get swinguserver.log under Tomcat 7.0\logs. How could I configure log4j to write log under webapps/ROOT/logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `${webApp.root}` please try to use `${catalina.home}`.

When you use `${catalina.home}`it will point to your tomcat directory. You can find `catalina.home` variable in your `catalina.sh` or `catalina.bat` file.

If you want log inside ROOT directory just edit the location as follows:

`${catalina.home}\/webapps\/ROOT\/logs\/swinguserver.log`.

This will direct the log to your `ROOT/logs` directory.

Comment: Hi SachinSarawgi, thank you for your time. When I change ${webApp.root} to ${catalina.home}, I can get swinguserver.log under Tomcat 7.0\logs. How could I configure log4j to write log under Tomcat 7.0/webapps/ROOT/logs? What's wrong with my ${webApp.root}?

Comment: @Rangtian did u tried giving full path (with ROOT/logs) mentioned in the answer??

Comment: You want to do this with webApp.root ?? Or above answer is okay.

Comment: Yes! It works! Your solution is very straightforward lol. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my webApp.root?

Comment: No idea but I was using catalina.home so I helped u

Comment: Appreciate your help :D

Comment: And also use forward slash and backslash both in this way your location will work in windows and linux both.